# How to pause setInterval when mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to pause setInterval when **mouse hover** ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var MyClass = $(".myclass");
  if (MyClass.hover()) {

  } else {
  setInterval(test, 1000);

  function test() {
    $("#color").click();
  }
  }
});
```

This code not work!

**[All code in Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/t5nvqzfe/)**

Comment: That link is button click! My question is mouse hover!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myClass = $(".myclass");

  function test() {
      $("#color").click();
  }
  
  var timerId = setInterval(test, 1000);
  
  myClass.hover(
    function() {
      window.clearInterval(timerId);
    }, function() {
      timerId = setInterval(test, 1000);
    }
  );
  
  
});

document.getElementById('color').onclick = changeColor; 
var currentColor = "red";
function changeColor() { 
  if(currentColor == "red"){ 
     document.body.style.color = "green";
     currentColor = "green";
  } else {
     document.body.style.color = "red";
     currentColor = "red";
  } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="color">
click
</button>

<div class="myclass">
Mouse Hover
</div>
<div id="myid" style="width:30px;height:30px;">
Change color
</div>
```